# Best way for MySQL Temporary tables in a Stored Procedure with once connection from a Server

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, stored-procedures

According to the MySQL Reference Manual

> You can use the TEMPORARY keyword when creating a table. A TEMPORARY table is visible only within the current session, and is dropped automatically when the session is closed. This means that two different sessions can use the same temporary table name without conflicting with each other or with an existing non-TEMPORARY table of the same name. (The existing table is hidden until the temporary table is dropped.)

Since a server (NodeJS in my scenario) maintains only one connection to the server it will surely conflict (use the same temporary table for different procedure calls)  the `TEMPORARY TABLES` used in the `STORED PROCEDURES` when **Asynchronous Calls** are made to the same stored procedure right ?

If yes, Whats the best way to overcome this ? Random table names ?

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be using an extra field in your temporary table and use a random number:

```
declare rnd float;

create temporary table if not exists temporary_table(
  ...
  rand_number float
);

set rnd = rand();

insert into temporary_table (...  ,rand_number)
   values (... , rnd);

/*do other stuffs using always rand_number field */


/*finally clear the temporary data*/


delete from temporary_table 
  where rand_number = rnd;
```

`rand()`  may return an existing value, you can check if exists to create another one